# My graph code not running and neither throwing any error?

Tags: java, graph-theory

I am trying to implement a graph. I am not able to understand why my code is not working. I tried to look where is it getting wrong but cannot figure out and my ide not giving any error also.
I am beginner can someone tell me where am i getting and why ?
I am posting my code below.

```
import java.util.*;
class Graph {

    private int V;
    private LinkedList<Integer>[] adjList ;

    Graph(int V) {

        adjList = new LinkedList[V];

        for(int i=0 ; i<V ; i++) {
            adjList[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        }
    }

    public void addEdge(int v, int w) {
        adjList[v].add(w);
    }

    public void printGraph(Graph graph) {
        for(int i=0 ; i<graph.V ; i++) {
            for(Integer pCrawl : graph.adjList[i]){
                System.out.print(pCrawl+" ");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph g = new Graph(4); 

        g.addEdge(0, 1); 
        g.addEdge(0, 2); 
        g.addEdge(1, 2); 
        g.addEdge(2, 0); 
        g.addEdge(2, 3); 
        g.addEdge(3, 3); 

        g.printGraph(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: I run it in online compiler and in vscode also it just shows this ```Note: Graph.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.``` Can you please tell me where am i getting wrong. So that i wont make this mistake again ? @Vajk

Comment: how should your output look?

Comment: @Niklas just spaced elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Graph` class has a field called `V`. There is also a parameter `int V` that is received by your constructor. They are not the same variable. Unless you initialise the field `V`, it will be zero.

So this loop

```
for(int i=0 ; i<graph.V ; i++)
```

exits immediately.

The way to set the field `V` to the received variable `V` in your constructor is by adding

```
this.V = V;
```

inside your constructor.

Comment: It worked now, but I am not able to understand the concept behind it ? why we I have to write this.V ?

Comment: Your `Graph` class has a field called `V`. There is also a parameter `int V` that is received by your constructor. They are not the same variable. Unless you initialise the field `V`, it will be zero.

Answer (score 1):

You need ti initilaize `V` like: `this.V = V;` inside the constructor. another thing the method `printGraph` does not neet to recieve Graph varibale and you can write it like:

```
public void printGraph() {
    for(int i=0 ; i<V ; i++) 
        for(Integer pCrawl : adjList[i])
            System.out.print(pCrawl+" ");              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print a entire line to manage the y-axis and limit i by the count of elements in your adjList:

```
    public void printGraph(Main graph) {
        for(int i=0 ; i<graph.adjList.length ; i++) {
            for(Integer pCrawl : graph.adjList[i]){
                System.out.print(pCrawl+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

Which will output the following:

> 1 2 
>   2 
>   0 3 
>   3

If you want to rotate that, you simply need to change the adding Parameters :)